# Showing hidden div with jquery .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to validate a form with jQuery. I'm selecting all form fields that have `class="required"` and using `.each()` function to check if the field is empty. If it's  empty, I'm showing hidden div positioned relatively to the field.

Something is obviously wrong as the following code is failing:

```
$('#application').submit(function(){
var requiredFields = $('.required').val();
requiredFields.each(function(){
    if (requiredFields == ''){
        position = requiredFields.position();
        width = requiredFields.outerWidth();
        $("#error-wrapper-mail").css({
            visibility: "visible",
            top: (pos.top - 8) + "px",
            left: (pos.left + width + 25) + "px"
        }).hide().fadeIn("slow").delay(2700).fadeOut("slow");
        requiredFields.addCLass("not-valid").focus().delay(3500).queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("not-valid");
        });
        return false;
    }
}); });
```

If I select the input field by ID, the rest of the code works fine.

The markup:

```
<form role="form" id="application" action="add-customer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="Input-firstname">First name<span class="redstar"> * </span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="Input-firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name">
    <br />
    <label for="Input-lastname">Last name<span class="redstar"> * </span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="Input-lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name">
    <br />
    <label for="InputPass">Password<span class="redstar"> * </span></label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control  required" id="InputPass" name="pass" placeholder="Choose your password">
    <span class="help-block">Please create a password more than 6 symbols long, including uppercase letters, lowercase letters and digits.</span>
    ...
</form>
```

I'm new to jQuery and I'll be thankfull if someone can point me in the right direction

EDIT: Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7yLmq/

Comment: Just a side note, Its `addClass` instead of `addCLass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to loop between each `$('.required')` :

```
$('.required').each(function(){
   var requiredFields = $(this).val();
   // Your Code
});
```

Comment: Looks logical, but still not working... Thanks for the suggestion, maybe the problem is somewhere else..

Comment: Hi @Belgor if you want more help try to reproduce your problem in a http://jsfiddle.net  with the code you provide i can't reproduce that only suggest about the code i see :)

Comment: Yes, you are right.. This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7yLmq/ This is look pretty straightforward but i cant get it working..

Comment: you want the message appear for each field?

Comment: Yes, i want to have only one div which to use as a error message and show it relatively to the field which is empty

Comment: Play with this http://jsfiddle.net/7yLmq/34/ .... i can't work more right now on this but is an approach

Comment: Thanks Danko! You point me what i was needing. Finally i get it working with only one div which is showing and just focus the empty fields and give them red color, something totally enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could also be cleaned up by making use of a few other jQuery methods.

```
$('#application').submit(function(){
  $('.required').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
      $(this).closest('.help-block').fadeIn();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

This assumes that you will have one `help-block` per `required` input field. You could adapt this quite easily to move the `help-block` to the current `required` field however I don't see the point unless you want these messages to be loaded dynamically.